# Print a 2-dimensional array returned by SWIG interface in Python using swig methods

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, swig

I have the following C structure:

```
typedef struct _myS
{
  int x;
  int y;
} myS;

typedef struct _MyData
{
  int a[10][10];
  myS s[10][10];
} MyData;
```

It is filled by a C implementation and returned to Python as a SWIG object. My goal is print the 2d array in python.

I am trying to avoid using numpy.

Currently I have the integer data (for example) in the python script as

```
Swig Object of type 'int (*)[10]'
```

I tried the following in the interface, but it doesn't seem to work on the above swig object:

```
%array_functions( int, intArray );
%pointer_class(int, intp);
%array_functions( intp, intpArray );
%pointer_functions(int, intpf);
```

Could you please help me any tricks/tips for this?

**Edit 1:**
I got a solution working for primitive data type via typemaps (out) where we catch the int [ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE] as the pattern. We can convert it to Python List object for the 2D array.
Bad news is this doesn't work for custom structures and only works for primitive data types.